# Why does this split both elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
new_list =[]
fieldscopy = ['donkey   donkey2    donkey3']
print(fieldscopy)
for i in fieldscopy:
    new_list.append(i.rsplit(   )[0])
print(new_list)
```

It outputs

```
  ['donkey']
```

instead of

```
 ['donkey', 'donkey2', 'donkey3]
```

Any ideas on simple ways for me to get the latter result rather than just have the first element in there. Supposed to split at the spaces (/t) but doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Can you show an example with more than one value in `fieldscopy`? What should the output be, a single list, or a list of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `[0]`, you select only the first element of the split.  If you want all the elements, just take the result of `split` itself.  Here is one way:

```
new_list = []
fieldscopy = ['donkey   donkey2    donkey3']
print(fieldscopy)
for i in fieldscopy:
    new_list.extend(i.rsplit())
print(new_list)
```

Your code has many other questionable features.  Why iterate over `fieldscopy` if it only has one element?  Are you putting multiple spaces in the parentheses of `rsplit(   )` in the belief that it will split on multiple spaces?  (It won't.)  Why are you using `rsplit` instead of `split` anyway?  I suggest you read the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial) as well as the documentation for the functions you are calling.

Comment: It's part of a larger thing. I just did it like this so I could get this one specific thing answered.

Comment: And as for rsplit vs split, wasn't aware of the difference really. Plus I thought the parameter or thing you put into rsplit("    ") means it would split there.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
new_list =[]
fieldscopy = ['donkey   donkey2    donkey3']
new_list = re.findall(r'(\w+)',fieldscopy[0])
print(new_list)
['donkey', 'donkey2', 'donkey3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. You are looping through all elements in fieldscopy (which is exactly 1 string). Then you add the first word to the new list, which results in 'donkey'

Correct would be:

```
for i in fieldscopy.split( "    "):
    newlist.append(i)
```

However, that is unnecessary. You can just do:

```
newlist = fieldscopy.split("    ")
```

Comment: Looping because since this is a small part of a bigger thing, there are actually multiple lines in fields copy. Only put one here for the sake of example.

Comment: @SS' then just do another split before this to get the list of lines